# How to set a file that is owned by a user but not readable by the owner?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, proc

I'm looking through the `/proc` directory and, as user, I'm not able to list a directory even though it shows that user is the owner.

Why and how does this happen?

For instance, in `ls -l /proc/2323/map_files` it says `ls: reading directory '.': Permission denied`. But the owner is clearly user. The user can cd into the directory but not `ls`. Doing this as root is fine though.

Added Backstory:

Currently the process is using firejail, which is a setuid binary, to drop caps and namespace isolate firefox. Without firejail, everything works as expected, i.e. user is able to `ls map_files`, but with firejail, the map_files directory cannot be `ls` by the user, though `cd` is fine. It isn't a permissions issue, since the directory is user readable, and the files, which are symlinks to .so files show u+r as well.

Comment: What is the exact error? `Permission denied`? The folder in my Ubuntu under `/proc/.../` is named `map_files` with a final 's'.

Comment: Added more elucidation. I'm thinking it's a question of namespace or something else entirely.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the read permission from a file you own, and then you won't be able to read it anymore.

```
$ echo hello >foo
$ chmod u=w,go+r foo
$ ls -l foo
--w-rw-r-- 1 gilles gilles 6 Oct 20 15:13 foo
$ cat foo
cat: foo: Permission denied
```

This is not useful for security since the owner can change the file's permissions
at any time. It's just a consequence of how permissions work.

---

However, this doesn't explain what you're seeing in `/proc`. `/proc` is a somewhat special filesystem. With “ordinary” filesystems, when a process opens a file (or lists a directory, or reads a symbolic link's target), the kernel checks the process's credentials (i.e. what user it's running as and so on), reads the file's permissions, and checks whether the credentials give access to the file. But `/proc` doesn't work like this. The kernel applies specific checks, which are different for different files in `/proc`. Separately, when a process lists a directory, the kernel generates permissions which are an approximation of the checks performed when opening a file.

In particular, if a process is or has been running with elevated credentials (typically [setuid or setgid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), some information in `/proc` is not accessible to the user anymore, only to root. This is not reflected in the permissions. For example, consider a process that's running setgid. This process will have all files in `/proc` owned by the expected user and the permissions will be the same as for unprivileged processes. However, because the process may have had access to confidential information while it had the extra group privileges, the kernel no longer allows the user to perform operations that could exfilter this information. And so, for example, the user can't see what `/proc/$pid/cwd` points to, in case the process had changed to a directory that the user normally can't access. The user can't dump the process's memory through `/proc/$pid/mem`. The user can't see the process's memory maps through `/proc/$pid/map*` in case they reflected confidential information (and also to keep [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) effective). And so on.

Comment: I've added some new details in the opening post. Is it possible to get the euid from /proc/<pid> directory? Maybe from `status`? From /proc/pid/status i get Uid / Gid mappings and it shows that they're owned by the user, but the `map_files` cannot be `ls` by the user. I've also tried `stat -c "%u %g" <file>` as root to see ownership. Everything points to the user being able to `ls`. Currently the processes are in their own namespace, but when i `nsenter -t <pid> ` into the namespace as the user, the map_files directory is still not listable.

Comment: @placidchat The euid is the second number on the `Uid:` line in `/proc/$pid/status`. Because you ran `firejail`, your process is “tainted” with having had elevated privileges. It remains tainted after losing privileges, but I think fork+exec would result in an untainted process (not sure what does untaint). I don't know if there's an explicit “is-tainted” indicator in `/proc/$pid`, but you can see that indirectly from not being able to read `cwd` and `map_files` and so on.

Comment: There are symlinks like this in /proc/<pid> : `cwd -> /proc/113/fdinfo` , `root -> /proc/113/fdinfo` . which i assume are generated when a new namespace was started and the process was forked and execd in. The low process number indicates this. However, these processes are nowhere to be found even when i nsenter into /proc/pid to `ls`, so i'm not sure why these links are still reflected in /proc. I tried nsenter into every namespace that root could lsns as well, and couldn't find these processes.

Comment: @placidchat The files in `/proc` are generated on the fly when you try to access them (open a regular file for reading, opendir a directory, readlink a symlink), based on internal metadata in the kernel. They reflect the current status, as observed from the observing process's namespaces. You see `/proc/113` from a process that exists in the namespace you're observing it from. The existence of `/proc/113` is what makes `ps` decide to list process 113: `ps` gets all its information from `/proc`.

Comment: Yes i know that. To give a concrete example, the directory `/proc/4853/` has `cwd -> /proc/113/fdinfo` and `root -> /proc/113/fdinfo` . But the current /proc has no process 113. So i'm reasoning that it is because of a unshare+fork+exec, which is why the process id is so low. Additionally i've nsentered every pid in lsns and none of them have a process with this pid in them.

Comment: Right now, i'm running inotifywait on the /proc directory to see what gets created, to find out when the processes of these cwd->/proc/<pid>/fdinfo gets created

Comment: The other thing that is really interesting about this is, since firefox is running in an unshared space, it is supposed to be owned by the user running it. It isn't supposed to be able to get any elevated privileges. This is reflected in the permissions in `/proc/pid`, but the owner cannot view the files in `cwd` `map_files` `task/.../(fd|ns|etc)`.

Answer (score 2):

To set a file owned by user, but not readable by the same user is actually very easy:

```
chmod u-r file
```

If you do that - the only way to read the file would be to elevate your privileges or return read flag back (`u+r`).

The same goes for directories. Remove the user-read flag from it and the owner of the directory would not be able to `ls` it. Remove the executable flag from the directory (`u-x`) and the owner will lose ability to `cd` into that directory.

At the same time - these files and directories can access by other people (`o+r` and `o+x`). And of course they are always accessible by *root* who ignores permission flags.

Directories and files in `/proc` directory are representing processes, threads, shared memory objects. Their permissions are set by the application when it creates the thread/shared memory. So they do not respond to `chmod` tool, and attempting to change permission is a sure way to break the running application.
But `ls` and `cd` still obey the permission flags on the objects in `/proc`.
So if you really need to read something there - you have to elevate yourself to *root*.

Answer (score 1):

Its caused of user rights.

example:

```
[~] whoami
mm
[~] mkdir test
[~] echo "Hello World" > test/hello.txt
[~] ls -ld test
drwxr-xr-x 2 mm mm 4,0K 20. Okt 14:20 test
[~] chmod 111 test
[~] ls -ld test
d--x--x--x 2 mm mm 4,0K 20. Okt 14:20 test
[~] ls test
ls: cannot open directory 'test': Permission denied
[~, ERR:2] cat test/hello.txt
Hello World
[~] chmod 555 test
[~] ls -ld test
dr-xr-xr-x 2 mm mm 4,0K 20. Okt 14:20 test
[~] ls test
hello.txt
```

The folder rights differ from file rights. The `x` means you can access the folder but you can't look into it. To look into that folder you will need `r` too. And of cause `w` means you can write into that folder.

Comment: Welcome, try using `LC_ALL=C` before a command to get the messages in english, like `LC_ALL=C ls -ld test`, then [edit] the question replacing the messages, because this site is english only.

Comment: sorry, that was my fault. Thanks for the advice. I changed the post accordingly.

Comment: My language is spanish so I always use that trick to post here :)